# How to better present this data in WPF grid?

Tags: wpf, grid

I have some data presented in WPF Grid as follows:

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Style="{StaticResource SectionNumber}" Content="1.3"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 2">Number of grid in X:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 2">NX</Label>
            <lib:NumericTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5 2" Text="{Binding Parameters.NX}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 2">Number of grid in Y:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 2">NY</Label>
            <lib:NumericTextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5 2" Text="{Binding Parameters.NY}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 2">Type of data:</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 2">MD</Label>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbMD" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5 2" SelectedItem="{Binding Data.MD}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 2">Data value:</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 2">D</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5 2" Text="{Binding Data.D}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5 2" Text="{Binding Unit.LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
...
```

The problem is that I have hundreds of rows to write. In WinForms, I would probably write a user control to present a row of data, and I just need one line of code to create a row.

How can I simplify it here? Can DataTemplate help somehow? I know i can use DataTemplate in a listbox to make it easier. However, I need the columns to be aligned vertically, so I think Grid is the only way to go, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF ListView or DataGrid is the way to go.

I am writing a simple DataGrid XAML for you.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" >
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="YourColumnHeader1" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Content="{Binding Property1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="YourColumnHeader2" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <lib:NumericTextBox Text="{Binding Property2}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is that I have different types of column in the second column, e.g. textbox, comobobox, checkbox, and some rows have an extra column at the end for unit. How can I switch this? Is there a way to do it using trigers? I just updated my question with some more data.

Comment: See the DataTemplate in the sample there you cana have different content based on the type or some cases you can have DataTemplate.Triggers on it. DataGrid is exactly for this purpose, I would suggest you to read more on DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the hint again. I found a good example at http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html. The key point is to use DataTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a `DataGrid`, not a `Grid`.

Comment: I updated my question with more sample data. How can I put different kind of control (textbox, combobox, checkbox) into the second column?